# How can I check answer in an "interactive IDE code course"

Tags: javascript, ide, interactive, verification

I'm building a Blockchain code course with a classic "interactive IDE structure". The user will have to solve simple code problems and then submit their answer. The user screen is separated in two panels: Left is the doc/course, Right is a IDE (based on Monaco Editor).

My question is the following: How can I verify user answer? I have the user answer stored in a Vue Object (String). (Exemple:"`from somelibimport * \n\nTAG = 'course'`")

At the beginning, I planned to simply compare the user string with the exact required answer but it isn't flexible enough for something like that...

What would be the best option? I thought about getting all "required answer element" in an array and then check if the user answer contains all of it. Would it work ? Thanks and have a good day !

Comment: Yeah I think your right as well, you could have an array of mandatory lines to check through, and have some sort of evaluation to check the 'output' of the program.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, since it's Blockchain and Smart Contract programming it's nearly impossible to check any output :/ I think I'll stick with checking mandatory lines